# Display arduino serial data on a web browser via python

Tags: javascript, python, arduino, serial-port

I'm looking to get serial data from Arduino displayed from a web browser.

First, I put the data on a local host using bottle in python in json format

```
from bottle import route, run
import serial

dic = {}
ser = serial.Serial(port='COM6',baudrate=9600,timeout=None)

@route('/test')
def test():
    c = ser.readline()
    c = (str(c)[2:-5]) #just to get rid of the extra characters
    dic["val"] = c
    return(dic)

run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Then I proceed to read it using javascript

```
function getArduinoVals(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/test", function(data){
        $('#vals').html(data.val);
    });
    t = setTimeout("getArduinoVals()",50);
    });
}
getArduinoVals();
```

however, it doesn't seem to load from local host (I tested other URLs). How should I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you test it first with outputting some sample text such as "Hello World", to make sure your server is working and you have the correct URL? I would do that before testing the serial port...

Comment: yep I tested various pieces of text beforehand and it was all working. The serial port data does get printed but I want consistent updates which I thought could be accomplished via js

Answer (score 0):

You could use p5.serialport of p5.js for getting the serial data on the web browser. But you have to run the node server in the back.
https://github.com/vanevery/p5.serialport
You should check the github repo for getting started with p5.serialport.
p5.js is very similar to arduino code style so it's easier and convenient than python.